# Можно ли из View class перейти в Activity class или какая альтернатива?

Tags: java, android

Помогите пожалуйста новичку.
1. Я создал класс, расширяющий View. В нем рисую некоторые изображения на экране, а при нажатии в определенные области экрана - изменяю значения переменных и перерисовываю экран.
2. В Layout файле для активити добавляю этот расширяющий View класс.
3. По достижении определенного значения переменных, мне нужно перейти в следующее активити.
4. Весь код для действий я пишу в View классе.
**Вопрос:** 
Если из view класса я не могу через Intent перейти в новый активити, то как тогда мне запустить новый активити?
**Или** какой альтернативный путь мне выбрать (в чем именно разбираться)?
Код Активити, XML, и класса ниже:

```js
public class LevelDraw extends View{

    private int count;
    private float x, y;

    public LevelDraw(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        count = 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Рисование
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //code

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //code yes
                if (x > 0 && x < 100 && y > 0 && y < 100) {
                    count++;
                } else if (x > 100 && x < 200 && y > 0 && y < 100) {
                    //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ 
                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                    //startActivity НЕТУ в этом контексте
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

```js
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkBack"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.alieniqtest.GameActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/question"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"/>

    <com.example.android.alieniqtest.LevelDraw
        android:id="@+id/ld"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

В результате я имею вот такую картинку (Сюда вставлен код с вырезанными неважными для вопроса строчками):
[image: Скриншот экрана]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `LevelDraw` можно добавить метод

```
private IClickListener clickListener;    

public void setOnClickListener(IClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}
```

clickListener необходим для того, чтобы потом вызвать его

Затем, вместо этого

```
//ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ 
Intent i = new Intent(getContext.this, ThirdActivity.class);
//startActivity НЕТУ в этом контексте
startActivity(i);
```

Написать так

```
if (clickListener != null) {
    clickListener.onClick();
}
```

Сам интерфейс `IClickListener` будет вот такой

```
interface IClickListener {
    void onClick();
}
```

Тогда в `GameActivity` можно будет добавить clickListener к LevelDraw и уже из `GameActivity` открывать новую активити

```
LevelDraw levelDraw = (LevelDraw) findViewById(R.id.ld);
levelDraw.setOnClickListener(new IClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ сработал, как и ответ от Likhanov. Вы первый, поэтому галочку на ваш ответ. Только вопрос - чей ответ более правильный : ваш или Likhanov? Я не вижу каких-либо потенциальных опасностей типа утечек памяти и т.д. ни в вашем, ни в его ответах, но я тупой новичок.. поэтому спрашиваю.

Answer (score 0):

Занимался чем-то похожим недавно, то есть по сути вызовом методов `activity` из кастомного `View`. Для этого необходим метод, который вам и вернет экземпляр `activity`, расположите его в классе `View`

```
private Activity getActivity() {
    Context context = getContext();
    while (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
        if (context instanceof GameActivity) {
            return (Activity) context;
        }
        context = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

В самой `View` объявите нужную активити

```
private GameActivity mGameActivity;
```

И в нужном месте делайте запуск новой активити так:

```
mGameActivity = (GameActivity) getActivity();
if (mGameActivity != null)
    mGameActivity.startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), ThirdActivity.class));
```

Возможно это не самый лучший и безопасный вариант, но меня он не подводил.

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ работает полностью, как и ответ от Valery Ponomarenko. Ваш вариант мне было чуть проще воспроизвести.   Только вопрос - чей ответ более правильный : ваш или Валерия? Я не вижу каких-либо потенциальных опасностей типа утечек памяти и т.д. ни в вашем, ни в его ответах, но я тупой новичок.. поэтому спрашиваю.

Comment: думаю вариант с интерфейсом лучше в плане архитектуры приложения

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и пояснение!